# jQuery append image to div animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, gallery

I think this question is best explained by giving you a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2mrh/1/). In that example, when the user clicks on of the gallery items, an image is appended to the div with `id="showimage"`. What I cannot work out how to do is pass in the parameter of the image clicked, and display that image instead of an absolute one.

It should function as follows:

- If image 1 is clicked, image 1 should be appended into `showimage`.
  It should animate from width 0px to width 10% of the parent div.
- If image 1 is clicked again, it should collapse: it should animate
  from width 100% to width 0px
- If any other img is clicked while there is already an image in `showimage`, the image already inside should collapse, and the new one expand in its place

I think this would be best accomplished by 3 functions:

1. Expand - append to `showimage` and animate from 0px to 100%
2. Collapse - animate from 100% to 0px and remove from `showimage`
3. Replace - call collapse on the image already in `showimage`, and call expand on the image clicked

Thanks in advance, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: i've just modified your code in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z2mrh/5/ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem, and you can see a live jsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/6vVUS/16/).

I kept the code really neat for this one - 3 separate functions, and 1 if statement to check if the showimage div had content.

The jQuery I used was as follows:

```
var add_image = function(clicked) {
    var image_create = '<img src="' + clicked + '">';
    $('#showimage').hide().append(image_create).slideDown(400);
};

var change_image = function(clicked) {
    $('#showimage img').slideUp(400, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        add_image(clicked);
    });
};

var remove_image = function() {
    $('#showimage img').slideUp(400, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
};

$('.gallery').click(function() {
    var len = $('#showimage').children().length;
    var clicked = $("img", this).attr('src');
    if (len === 0) {
        add_image(clicked);
    } else if (len === 1) {
        change_image(clicked);
    }
});

$('#showimage').click(function() {
    remove_image();
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

here I forked your fiddle and made it work as you want

http://jsfiddle.net/6vVUS/5/

Comment: There is a bug on the third click which I can't seem to eliminate - do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Without the animation in place. Your code should look something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('div.gallery').click(function (event) {

        var len = $('#showimage').find('img').length;
        var myimage = '<img src="http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/302239_CauyLQoHZTkSJkkGnr3kVbFtw.jpg">';

        if (len === 0) {
            appendImage();

        }
       else {

            $('div#showimage').empty();
            appendImage();
      }

    });  

    function appendImage() {

       $('div#showimage').append(myimage);
       // your animation here 
    }  
});​
```